# Slow boot on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, performance

After installing Ubuntu 18.04 on my new Dell Laptop, I'm wondering wether it is possible to speed up the booting process. Here is some basic information:

`systemd-analyze`:

```
Startup finished in 3.879s (kernel) + 28.444s (userspace) = 32.323s
graphical.target reached after 28.001s in userspace
```

`systemd-analyze blame`:

```
    11.425s dev-sda3.device
     10.386s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      8.797s plymouth-start.service
      6.751s dev-loop1.device
      6.719s dev-loop2.device
      6.599s dev-loop3.device
      6.574s dev-loop4.device
      6.565s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.551s dev-loop5.device
      6.524s dev-loop7.device
      6.499s dev-loop8.device
      6.277s fwupd.service
      6.075s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-154.mount
      5.736s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-86.mount
      5.687s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-64.mount
      5.656s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-39.mount
      5.621s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-31.mount
      5.245s dev-loop0.device
      2.778s udisks2.service
      2.604s networkd-dispatcher.service
      2.529s grub-common.service
      2.457s snapd.service
      2.187s gpu-manager.service
      2.057s accounts-daemon.service
      2.052s ModemManager.service
      2.017s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-36.mount
      1.946s apport.service
      1.681s systemd-udevd.service
      1.641s bolt.service
      1.618s dev-loop11.device
      1.574s dev-loop6.device
      1.573s dev-loop12.device
      1.552s dev-loop9.device
      1.543s keyboard-setup.service
      1.508s dev-loop10.device
      1.403s NetworkManager.service
      1.385s bluetooth.service
      1.379s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-167.mount
      1.370s rsyslog.service
      1.206s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       929ms thermald.service
       843ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       835ms systemd-journald.service
       813ms dev-mqueue.mount
       810ms dev-hugepages.mount
       802ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       756ms systemd-sysctl.service
       706ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-59.mount
       690ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-408C\x2d72C2.service
       687ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-69.mount
       660ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-25.mount
       648ms polkit.service
       644ms snap-spotify-13.mount
       635ms systemd-modules-load.service
```

and `systemd-analyze critical-chain`:

```
     graphical.target @28.001s
     └─multi-user.target @28.000s
      **└─kerneloops.service @24.171s +21ms**
        └─network-online.target @24.169s
         **└─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @17.603s +6.565s
          └─NetworkManager.service @16.197s +1.403s**
           └─dbus.service @15.305s
            └─basic.target @14.841s
             └─sockets.target @14.841s
              **└─snapd.socket @14.799s +41ms**
               └─sysinit.target @14.790s
                **└─systemd-timesyncd.service @14.580s +210ms
                  └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @14.181s +366ms**
                    └─local-fs.target @14.177s
                      └─run-user-120.mount @18.907s
                        └─swap.target @13.501s
                          **└─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-91bef5fa\x2dfe6b\x2d441f                 \x2d92c3\x2dcf857dacef7e.swap @13.355s +145ms**
                            └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-91bef5fa\x2dfe6b\x2d441f\x2d92c3\x2dcf857dacef7e.device @13.354s
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to speed up the booting process?

Comment: I'd say 32 seconds is as good as it gets with Gnome3 and systemd. You could try to remove snaps and to disable services, but I am not sure you'd want it.

Comment: Can you provide your HW specs? Especially CPU, RAM and HDD type. Your simple “Dell Laptop” info does not say much about performance…

Comment: @ WinEunuuchs2Unix Yes
@Melebius Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz, DDR4, SATA.
Is that sufficient or do you need the full output of lshw?

Answer (score 1):

### 18.04 with no swap partition

There is a glitch where Ubuntu 18.04 is boots slow when there is no swap partition. To circumvent this edit `/etc/default/grub` and search for the line with `LINUX` and add `noresume` after `quiet splash`. It will look something like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash noresume"
```

Then save the file and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not change the booting time.

Comment: @DominikB. I revised the answer.